# How can I access polymorphic_path inside a model in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

Pretty simple, I want to use the `polymorphic_path` method inside a Rails 4 model. Yes I know it's poor separation of concerns. And I know about `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`, but `polymorphic_path` isn't in there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try including also `PolymorphicRoutes`:

```
include ActionDispatch::Routing::PolymorphicRoutes
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

def link
  polymorphic_path(self)
end
```

Comment: Hah, tried each of those individually but not together. Works perfectly.

Comment: @markets, this works for me inside a model as well, but not inside a helper module... edit: made it a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035963/how-to-use-polymorphic-path-in-lib-module-in-rails-4

Comment: When using non-polymorphic urls, I used to be able to do `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.todo_path( ... )` but that doesn't work with `polymorphic_url`. You *have* to include `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` in the class and then use it with `polymorphic_url`. Odd.

Answer (score 1):

I know the OP specified Rails 4 but in case someone else ends up here looking for the answer using Rails 5 like I did, here are two ways to **access `polymorphic_path` in a model in Rails 5**:

```
class Something
    # The following line is enough, no need for ActionDispatch::Routing::PolymorphicRoutes in Rails 5
    include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end
```

Or, if you want to avoid including all methods, just add a private method that wraps the call and you're good to go!

```
class Something
    def do_stuff
       polymorphic_path(a_resource)
    end

    private

    def polymorphic_path(resource)
        Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.polymorphic_path(resource)
    end
end
```

Notice that the class doesn't need to inherit from ApplicationRecord, both methods work with POROs (Plain-Old Ruby Object).