# How to use polymorphic_path in lib/module in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to call [polymorphic_path](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html#method-i-polymorphic_path) in a helper module located at `lib/my_module.rb`.

I tried the following from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003252/how-can-i-access-polymorphic-path-inside-a-model-in-rails-4), which works in a model, but not in my module:

```
module MyModule
  include ActionDispatch::Routing::PolymorphicRoutes
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def link(model)
    polymorphic_path(model)
  end
end
```

I get:

```
undefined method `polymorphic_path' for MyModule:Module
```

Btw, I load my module through `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` in `config/application.rb`.

Comment: You should create an answer for your own question and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out you have to create a class to properly include stuff in ruby, for example:

```
class MyClass
  include ActionDispatch::Routing::UrlFor
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def link(model)
    polymorphic_path(model)
  end
end
```